# How to create function that return a Date object?

Tags: javascript, function, date, object

1 - Make a function that given a date in text format "dd/mm/yyyy" returns a Date object with that date, using the `Split()` method.

2 - You have to do a "console.log() of the Date object created" and it should output something similar to

`Mon Dec 2 2019 11:36:25 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)`.

I have tried this but I don't know why when I write a `console.log`

I get the following:
`2022-12-05T00:00:00.000Z`

And I try to get it to appear something like this:

`Mon Dec 2 2019 12:30:05 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)`

```
function convertDate(date) {
    let dateArray = date.split("/");
    let DateString = dateArray[2] + "/" + dateArray[1] + "/" + dateArray[0] + "Z";
    let dateDate = new Date(dateString);
    return dateDate;
}

console.log(convertDate("05/12/2022"));
```

Comment: Use `console.log(dateDate.toString())`.

Comment: '*we must first change the format of the date and then add a Z to the end: “2022/12/01Z”*'. That is a very bad idea, see [*Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results)

Answer (score -1):

you can use new Date() to get the date like  "Wed Dec 28 2022 11:36:25 GMT+0100"

```
let date = new Date("05/12/2022");
console.log(date);
```

output will be Thu May 12 2022 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time) {}

Comment: See [*Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results)